# Access 2016 - Using an IIf statement with the Count function

Tags: ms-access, count, iif

`=Count([item]) & IIf([Count]>1," Items","Item)`

I am trying to use this in a text box on a form in Access 2016 to create a count of rows with the text "Items" if there are more than 1 and Item if there is only 1. So it would result in either "3 Items" or "1 Item" The count function works, I get the right number of rows, but I always get "Items", even when there is only 1 item. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Can I use Count() with an IIf expression?
Many thanks, Scott

Comment: You're missing the closing parentheses for "Item**"**, so it's being ignored?

Comment: What is [Count]? You have a field with this name? If so, rename it, Count is reserved word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Count([item])` doesn't magically create a variable `[Count]` that you can use afterwards. You have to repeat the expression:

```
=Count([item]) & IIf(Count([item]) > 1, " Items", " Item")
```